# How to extract profile from a pure host-and-credentials Cisco AnyConnect VPN client connection?

Tags: cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

My Cisco AnyConnect client 4.6 for Windows successfully connects to a server: prompts hostname, then group, username, password.

No profiles configured in *C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile*.

I'd like to change some connection settings which are usually stored in the profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/ AnyConnectProfile.xsd">
<ClientInitialization>
    <ShowPreConnectMessage>false</ShowPreConnectMessage>
    <AutoConnectOnStart>true</AutoConnectOnStart>
    <MinimizeOnConnect>true</MinimizeOnConnect>
    <LocalLanAccess>true</LocalLanAccess>
    <AutoUpdate>true</AutoUpdate>
    <WindowsLogonEnforcement>SingleLocalLogon</WindowsLogonEnforcement>
    <WindowsVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</WindowsVPNEstablishment>
    <AllowManualHostInput>false</AllowManualHostInput>
</ClientInitialization>
<ServerList>
    <HostEntry>
        <HostName>vpn.example.com</HostName>
        <HostAddress>vpn.example.com</HostAddress>
        <UserGroup>Example</UserGroup>
    </HostEntry>
</ServerList>
```

Unfortunately, the profile.xml above fails to connect with the following logs:

```
  12:09:39 AM    Connection attempt has failed.
  12:09:40 AM    No valid certificates available for authentication.
```

I guess the server provides some default profile settings on each connect.
Is it possible to replicate it like a file-based profile configuration which works exactly the same way as the one received from the server?

Answer (score 1):

If profile has **UserGroup** (i.e., tunnel group) entry for a host entry, AnyConnect client behaves differently. Meaning, profile mandates user explicitly connecting to the **UserGroup** for that host entry. In such scenario, VPN server (i.e., ASA) will not present other tunnel groups available on the ASA. User strictly has to pass authentication (username/password or certificate) configured for that tunnel group on ASA.

For directly connecting to a specific user group to work, admin has to configure group-url for that user group on ASA. In your case, group-url that needs to be configured is *https://vpn.example.com/Example* for the user group *Example*. You can do this via -

- ASA CLI help on configuring group-url: [web vpn attributes](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/vpngrp.html#wp1045173) or
- Through AnyConnect Connection Profiles -> Advanced section on ASDM

If group-url is not configured, AnyConnect fails connection for directly connecting to specific user group which is what I suspect happening in your case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have access to ASA, I just connect to VPN entering host, username, and password into VPN client prompt.
The idea was just adding the option AllowRemoteUsers to my connection.

Comment: AnyConnect VPN connection settings can not be enforced by modifying the profile locally. Even though if you modify locally, on the connection attempt AnyConnect Downloader will update the file reverting the changes. What you are trying to achieve can be done only by an ASA admin by configuring a profile to your requirements to the tunnel group you are connecting to.

Comment: BTW, if you have just modified the **ClientInitialization** settings in the existing VPN profile, then connection attempt can be failing for a different reason. Please run Cisco DART tool and share the logs if you are interested in knowing the failure reason.